# How to create existing JSON in groovy, using JsonBuilder?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I'm looking for definition (structure) of object that can be converted to following JSON

```
 {
    "header":{
        "callbackUrl":"",
        "clientOrderId":"A565132",
        "clientOriginationId":"2345FE",
        "serviceProvider":"VERIZON",
        "transactionId":"EEDT44567"
    },
    "customer": {
        "nationalIdType":"",
        "nationalId":"",
        "addresses":[
            {
                "type":"WORK",
                "postalCode":"330066"
            }
        ],
        "serviceProviderAuthentication":[
            {
                "passcode":"",
                "securityQuestion":"",
                "securityAnswer":""
            }
        ]
    },
    "accountPhoneNumber":"",
    "accountNumber":""
}
```

Comment: Please add a description of what this JSON is and what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an example of how [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) would be used to create the JSON you've given, here it is

```java
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

json header: [
        callbackUrl:"",
        clientOrderId:"A565132",
        clientOriginationId:"2345FE",
        serviceProvider:"VERIZON",
        transactionId:"EEDT44567"
    ],
    customer:[
        nationalIdType:"",
        nationalId:"",
        addresses: [
            [
                type:"WORK",
                postalCode:"330066"
            ]
        ],
        serviceProviderAuthentication:[
            [
                passcode:"",
                securityQuestion:"",
                securityAnswer:""
            ]
        ]
    ],
    accountPhoneNumber:"",
    accountNumber:""

json.toString()
```

You might have been confused about how to create a JSON that doesn't have a root.  The answer is: by passing a map.

Comment: I looking for definition (structure) of object that can be converted to fallowing JSON

Comment: I'm going to delete this answer since apparently it's not what you needed.  Can you edit your question to explain in more detail what you need? If this isn't it, then I don't know what you're looking for. It sounds like you're looking for an object that something like Jackson would map to JSON, yet you tagged the question with jsonbuilder.